# Работа с JSON данными

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mvc

Здравствуйте, ищу библиотеку для работы с данными в JS. Есть JSON данные, которые приходят из REST API. Нужно с этими данными работать: добавлять(с валидацией), изменять, фильтровать, сортировать и т.д. и т.п. а затем собрать обратно все в JSON и отправить данные в REST API. Пример данных из REST API:

```
[
  { id:1, name:'A', city: 'C' },
  { id:2, name:'B', city: 'D' }
];
```

Работаю с ReactJS, поиски привели к Flux и тому подобным, но если я правильно понял, Flux - это метод проектирования, ну т.е. в store только хранятся данные, а Dispatcher обрабатывает события.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону [jsonQ](http://ignitersworld.com/lab/jsonQ.html), насколько я понимаю, она должна удовлетворять Вашим требованиям.

Есть еще одна библиотека, которая помогает организовать JSON с вложенными данными, но она уже Вам менее подходит.
[normalizr](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!